# JSF templating - header doesn't show while faces-redirect is not set as "true" Primefaces

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces, templating

I am writing a simple page using JSF and Primefaces.
This is my template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" header="North - header" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <h:form>
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="West - menu" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <h:form>
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Center - content" style="font-size: 15px;">
            <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" header="East - nothing" style="font-size: 15px;">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" header="South - footer" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:head>

<h:body>
</h:body>

</html>
```

I have made simple menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<ui:composition>
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Main">
            <p:menuitem value="Show main" action="glowna?faces-redirect=true"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Show resultPage" action="resultPage?faces-    redirect=true"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Pictures" action="obrazek?faces-redirect=true"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

And now: I wanted to add some content to "content" unitlayout. I made simple page which uses the template below. If I add to the menuitem action like: action="glowna", when I click that item while my page is running, all the template is shown but without header part.
The left, right, center and footer part is shown properly, but header disappears.
However, if I add to the action atribute faces-redirect=true (action="glowna?faces-redirect=true") everything works fine.

This is my content page: glowna.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Oto zawartość strony głownej - content</h1>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <p:inputText value="#{user.imie}" required="true"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{user.nazwisko}" required="true"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Show it!" actionListener="#{user.click}" update="growl"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Anyone knows why? 
Be grateful for ansewers :)

Comment: Shouldn't the template define it's p:layout element in the body, and not the head?

Comment: ive tried both of these options, nothing helped :)